# How to change css for an element but keep defaults for it's children

Tags: html, css

I want to set a certain font-family for a div, but I want it's children to keep the default properties. Is this possible?

Comment: What about overriding the child elements to the default properties? http://jsfiddle.net/R8pxb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, because if an inner element does not itself have any value set for a particular property, it will inevitably inherit it from its parent, if the property is defined with “Inherited: yes” in CSS specifications. This is, in essence, the very idea of inheritance.

There are not many situations where authors really want to preserve *default* values for properties, since the defaults are browser-dependent and often unsuitable (e.g., the most common default for `font-family` is `Times New Roman`).

It is possible that you actually meant something else, like preserving the property values that are set elsewhere in your style sheet. That would be a completely different issue, and the answer would then be that this happens automatically. If things don’t seem to work that way, the reason is probably a misunderstanding of the cascade. If you have a `span` element with some property set, then that value will apply, no matter what value you set for an enclosing `div` element. But the `span` element does not inherit a property from the `body` element, for example, except possibly indirectly (via the `div` element).

Assuming that you really want to preserve the *default* values for elements inside the `div` element, here’s how I do things on a small a hands-on exercise page (for playing with CSS). There’s a `div` containing some sample content, to be styled, and at the start, it must appear unstyled (except for the external dimensions and border for the `div`). I do this simply so that I group all the other content on the page inside containers with a specific `class` attribute. Then I simply set *all* the CSS settings for the page so that all selectors contain a class selector for that class. It’s a bit clumsy, but simple.

Answer (score 0):

Set the style for the element and reset it for all children:

```
#div {
  font-family: 'Inconsolata';
}

#div > * {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution. The concept of CASCADE INHERITANCE has been lost

Comment: it didn't reset, it redefined to "sans-serif". but I don't have other solutions from pure css, may be javascript/jquery is needed.

Comment: @odiszapc: It you know what values you are modifying and how they are inherited, resetting them is trivial.

Comment: @AbbyChauYuHoi: I'm just providing an example. Storing defaults and recalling them later is not possible with CSS, so if the OP has access to the original values of the overriden properties, re-defining them is not complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no posibilities in CSS to to this without defining styles for inner elements